# Can I set margin with percentages

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want set Margin with percentages in my code. Im working with Xamarin.Forms (XAML). Thanks a lot for your attention.

I tried things like this: Margin="5*" and Margin="5%" but give me a error.

```
<Button Text="{Binding Name}"
     TextColor="White"
     ContentLayout="Top"
     BackgroundColor="Transparent"
     BorderColor="White"
     BorderWidth="2"
     CornerRadius="6"
     Margin="5"/>
```

[What im trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr4ei.png)

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true"
                    FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" FlowLastTappedItem="{Binding LastTappedItem}"
                    FlowItemsSource="{Binding MyCategories}" >

                    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Text="{Binding Name}"
                                TextColor="White"
                                ContentLayout="Top"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                BorderColor="White"
                                BorderWidth="2"
                                CornerRadius="6"
                                Margin="5"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

                </flv:FlowListView>
```

Comment: The simple answer is no.

Comment: I think not possible.. The * property is used in heightdefenitions and width defenition in grid  ;)

Comment: @Skin well, after looking at your profile and knowing that you are Xamarin Developer how would you go about my problem? Cause i need to scale it for different screen sizes.

Comment: @AndroDevil yeah, i use * for my grids but now I need to scale different objects not related to the grid.

Comment: @LOLJovem what do you want the margin to be a percentage of? The height? Width? Both? Another visual element?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem? What is the issue you facing? Screenshots will be useful

Comment: @Skin Both, I can show you what im want to do.

Comment: @LOLJovem yeah, add screen shots.

Comment: @Skin i posted a screenshot of what im doing, i want to put that space between buttons, but with percentages, because the screen sizes may vary.

Comment: Ok, for that, use a grid and set the column and row spacing to be the appropriate values and then fill the entire grid content with a button in each cell. Think from the outside in, not the inside out. Make sense? Grids can be se set relatively, like * or even weighted *’s. If you need to alter the row and column spacing if the OnIdiom changes (ie tablet v phone) then you have to manage that through static resources in styles or some sort of approach like that.

Comment: @Skin Sorry, i didnt remember that im using a FlowListView, and thats why I cant do a Grid for the spacing. I will show my code so that you can know what is my problem.

Comment: You can use grid in  data template of flowlistview i think.

Comment: @LOLJovem throw that button in a container like a stacklayout or grid and set the padding on it.

Comment: @Skin But I can work with percentages with padding?

Comment: @AndroDevil I dont know how I can work with RowDeifinitions and ColumnDefinitions inside FlowListView.

Comment: @LOLJovem no, not in XAML but you could in C# by calculating the percentage. For what you want to do, I’d drop the thought of using a percentage because on a tablet vs phone, still, a percentage may not do it for you, you’ll likely find that it’s not enough on a phone but perfect on a tablet. Look at using OnIdiom and OnPlatform to set some hard values to make it pixel perfect. It’s not hard and gives you a lot more control and still works with styling.

Comment: @Skin Ok I will do that. Thanks a lot for your attention. Have a great day.

Comment: @LOLJovem sorry if that’s not what you want to hear but that’s be my approach. Good luck! I have some examples if you want some help.

Comment: @Skin I want work with percentages and if thats the only way I need do it. If I could do that in xaml file would be great but isnt a problem do it in a cs file. I just want to know if I run this app with two differents phone resolutions looks kinda the same.

Comment: How about using Collection View? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-grid